# python error when placing parent and child classes in separate files

Tags: python, module, parent-child

i am trying to initialise a parent module from a child module with the following structure:

```
$ cat caller.py
#!/usr/bin/env
import child

$ cat parent.py
class parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "initialised parent"

$ cat child.py
import parent
class child(parent):
    def __init__(self):
        print "initialised child"
```

however i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "caller.py", line 3, in <module>
    import child
  File "child.py", line 2, in <module>
    class child(parent):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Wow, that bit about metaclasses in the error message is a good way to scare off novices, isn't it… Fortunately, they fixed that in Python 3. It still might not be obvious to a novice what they did wrong, but at least it's not as terrifying…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to use the `parent` *module* object as a class. You need to use the class object from the module:

```
import parent

class child(parent.parent):
    def __init__(self):
        print "initialised child"
```

or import the class into the global namespace from the module:

```
from parent import parent

class child(parent):
    def __init__(self):
        print "initialised child"
```

Comment: ooooh of course haha thanks. will accept in 10 minutes when stackoverflow lets me :)

Comment: As a side note - it's normal to have classes (but not modules) starting in uppercase. So Child and Parent. class Child(parent.Parent)

Comment: @AidanKane: And part of the reason for that convention (enshrined in PEP 8) is that makes it harder to make mistakes like this.

Comment: @mulllhausen To understand when you are doing this error read carefully the traceback: `module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)`. Here it mentions `module.__init__()` but you *never* use `module` at all! In fact only in *really* rare circumstances you have to call `module` explicitly. Probably only when writing custom importers and such. "Normal" python code *never* references `module`, let alone calling its constructor.

Comment: Indeed. It's interesting how 'unnatural' it feels to be reading it all in lowercase.

Comment: @Bakuriu thanks for the tip, but i would have to know a lot more about python to even understand that this was what the error message was telling me :P

Comment: @AidanKane: Except, of course, that the stdlib is still full of cases like that. Like `datetime.datetime`, one of the prime examples that motivated the convention, which still violates it in 3.4. So you're forced to deal with the unnaturalness all the time. Maybe in Python 4000…